# Loading .json files to a HTML template using a HTML form for specific .json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a load of different .json files which I would like to enter the name of to a HTML page (local) form in order to load this information to a table.

My HTML form looks like this:

```
  <form>
    File: <input type="text" Id="file_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Load file" onclick="filltable()">
  </form>
```

My table header is this:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sample</th>
      <th>Variant</th>
      <th>Depth</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

My javascript script is this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

  function filltable() {
    var name = document.getElementById("file_name").value +".json";
  };

  $.getJSON(name,function(stuff){
    var items = [];
    $.each(stuff, function(key, val){
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.sample+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.variant+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.depth+"</td>");
    });
    $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
  });


</script>
```

I have also tried to embed the .getJSON code into my filltable() function, so that it is called when the submit button is clicked - but this doesnt work. If i replace:

"$.getJSON(name,function(stuff){"

with:

".getJSON("file1.json",function(stuff{"

then it loads fine - I just want to be able to load different files using the input.

Comment: `fillTable()` doesnt do anything because it ends after you do `var name = `

Comment: ok but I do get the variable 'name' as if i do console.log or alert (name) then it is whatever I put in the input - so why, if i embed the $.get.JSON code into that function does it not fill the table?

Comment: the $get.JSON code works fine when I put my .json file in the filepath - just not when I use it with the name variable

Comment: Try using the native `insertRow()`  called from the table object

Comment: also make sure that in the `file_input` textbox  that you only enter `file1`  and not `file1.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  var name = document.getElementById("file_name").value +".json";
  $.getJSON(name,function(stuff){
    var items = [];
    $.each(stuff, function(key, val){
      items.push("<tr>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.sample+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.variant+"</td>");
      items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.depth+"</td>");
    });
    $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
  });
  return false;

});
```

Comment: I have tried this, it does not work - I am confused why the variable 'name' isnt loading this file as it is obtained by the input form

Comment: Please go to http://jsfiddle.net/7wpnL/905/ and enter https://api.myjson.com/bins/rc3sb as the file name

Comment: this works - why would this not work when I use it on my browser?

Comment: It works now!!! thank you - I had an incorrect variable - thanks so much!